# SQL Server - API Request with T-SQL

Tags: json, sql-server, api, t-sql

I am attempting to hit an API via T-SQL, but am struggling to get any results. Each time I run the logic below I get no errors or data, just a blank response.

I  have 3 keys:

- Api-User-Name
- Client-Id
- Nonce

Content-Type of "application/json".

Appreciate any help I can get.

```
DECLARE @Object INT;
DECLARE @ResponseText VARCHAR(8000);

DECLARE @Json AS TABLE
(
    JsonTable NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get','www.urllink.com', 'false'

EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Api-User-Name', 'hidden'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Client-Id', 'hidden'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Nonce', 'hidden'

EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', NULL

INSERT INTO @Json (JsonTable) EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText'

SELECT * FROM @Json

EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Comment: Your first mistake is doing an HTTP call from T-SQL by going through COM. As you've discovered, effective error handling is difficult, and monitoring things is even less convenient. This is in addition to any firewall or resource issues. Strongly consider using client code for this instead (even something as primitive as a script triggered from a scheduled job is better). At the very least, if you have working client code you can inspect the request to see what it should look like, and compare it to what the T-SQL code is producing (with a packet sniffer or proxy).

Comment: I actually have this data already being parsed daily via a cron job, but I need it to be live via SSRS paginated reporting for a particular project. So I figured I would attempt to write some sort of SPROC that could pull the data each time the report is refreshed by the end user.

Comment: This topic has been discussed many times - along with the problems of your selected approach. Surely you have read some of these and seen the issues with using this error-prone ole-automation interface. Short answer - no one but you can debug this. Better answer - use a CLR procedure if you must do this via tsql. Issue to consider - perhaps doing this every time a "report" is requested might not be the most effective or efficient way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Now might be a good time to check out PowerBI, as it's especially powerful at combining data from multiple and external sources, unlike SSRS. Of course migrating from an existing SSRS setup to PowerBI might be very involved, so it's not a panacea.

Comment: You might want to look at using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: Use Powershell if you really can't bear doing this in C# or other client language. SQL is not the place for this, and those stored procedures have numerous issues as you have found

Comment: The code doesn't error because it's not checking for errors. Each of the sp_OA calls should have their return status checked: if 0 continue, otherwise call sp_OAGetErrorInfo to find out what the problem was and clean up. That said... 32-bit OLE code should not be used any more, it can't be used beyond on-prem Windows-based SQL Servers, so will never be portable to Linux-based SQL servers or cloud-hosted SQL. As stated by others this sort of thing should be external to SQL Server itself, but if you really absolutely must have it inside SQL Server write it in SQL CLR procedures.